# create android help screen

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I try to make help screen that cover main page when application is first runs. Like in this image. Any one help me for this task

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I think the EASIEST way perhaps would be to overlay your main function view with an standard view that is black, then using the alpha propery to allow your main view to come through, then an ImageView or something like that again on top of the alpha blended view.

There are of course potentially other ways of doing this, but this MAY be the easiest.

You could alternatively have a single imageview that comes up whose background is already translucent, then you would potentially only have to have an imageView and not the second view (as stated above).

Depending on what layout type you are using, you may have to do this as a popover so that it can truly be layed out on top of instead of linearly laid out, or relatively laid out, etc...

Comment: I've done things like that, but it does not run as expected. I still can interact with the page behind